Publishing and Consuming swift Artifacts as package dependencies in xcode project

I have a package repository on aws azure (a swift package name lets say SimplePackage)
I have created a repository in Code Artifacts section name (artifactsRepo)
Now I have followed Configure Swift with CodeArtifact section (manually configuration)
I do not have an aws cli setup done on my machine.
I have received the auth token and repository end point url from the person having the access.
I am navigated to the SimplePackage folder in terminal and executed below command:
swift package-registry login {artifactsrepourl}/login --token {auth token}
It is running successfully giving below response:

Login successful.

Credentials have been saved to the operating system's secure credential store.
Registry configuration updated.


Running the below command cat .swiftpm/configuration/registries.json gives value:

{
  "authentication" : {

  },
  "registries" : {
    "[default]" : {
      "supportsAvailability" : false,
      "url" : "{mycodeartifactrepourl}"
    }
  },
  "version" : 1
}


I executed swift package-registry set {mycodeartifactrepo} command.

Finally, I executed swift package-registry publish myScope.SimplePackage 1.0.0 command. This command neither give any error or success simple gives the next pointer.

It has created a package.swift file and an archive file inside the version folder in the codeartifact repo.

I feel the publish to code artifact is done successfully (not sure whether the .zip is fine or not)

Now when I tried to consume the package in the Xcode project via add dependency dialog and writing "myScope.SimplePackage". It does not find the package. I am not sure what exactly I am missing and stuck here.


Any help will be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
References:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/configure-swift.html
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-add-your-swift-packages-to-aws-codeartifact/

I finally got the solution of the problem.
I was using xcode 14.1, I upgraded mac and xcode to 15.3, tried the same steps mentioned in the question and the package dependency resolves successfully in the xcode project.
